# Not able to Render components in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to make a chat app in react native and Currently I am designing static chat screen which should look like this.

[image]

So what I am doing to make this kind of chat screen is I am making two seperate components Message Sender and Message Reciever

This is my MessageReciever Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';
import {  StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';


class MessageReciever extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>

        <Content>


          <Button style ={{marginLeft:22,marginTop:28,backgroundColor:'#F0F0F0',borderRadius:12,
                flexDirection:'column',height:'auto',width:280,alignItems:'stretch',flex:1,}} disabled>
                <Text style ={styles.nameText}>Jordan</Text>

                <Button transparent style ={{backgroundColor:'#F0F0F0',
                 height:'auto',width:280,alignItems:'stretch',borderRadius:12,flex:1}} disabled>

                    <Text  uppercase = {false} style ={styles.messageText} >Epo polam valayada? 
                     </Text>


                    <Text style ={styles.timeText}>08:23AM</Text>    

                </Button>

          </Button>   

        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    timeText:{
        fontSize:14,
        textAlign:'right',
        opacity:0.50,
        color:'#000000'

    },

    messageText:{
        fontSize:17,
        textAlign:'left',
        opacity:1.0,
        width:200,
        height:'auto',
        color:'#000000',
        alignItems:'stretch',

    },
     nameText:{
        fontSize:15,
        textAlign:'left',
        opacity:1.0,
        width:200,
        height:'auto',
        color:'green',
        alignItems:'stretch',


     },


})

export default MessageReciever;
```

and This is my MessageSender Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';
import {  StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';


class MessageSender extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>

                <Button style ={{backgroundColor:'#3399ff',
                  marginLeft:67,marginTop:28,borderRadius:12,
                  height:'auto',width:287,alignItems:'stretch',flex:1}} disabled>

                    <Text  uppercase = {false} style ={styles.messageText}>Players differentiation missing.
                            Notification for our own message? 
                     </Text>


                    <Text style ={styles.timeText}>08:23AM</Text>    

                </Button>


        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    timeText:{
        fontSize:14,
        textAlign:'right',
        opacity:0.50,
        color:'#FFFFFF'

    },

    messageText:{
        fontSize:17,

        opacity:1.0,
        width:210,
        height:'auto',
        color:'#FFFFFF',
        alignItems:'stretch',

    },
     nameText:{
        fontSize:15,
        textAlign:'left',
        opacity:1.0,
        width:200,
        height:'auto',
        color:'green',
        alignItems:'stretch',


     },



})

export default MessageSender;
```

And this is my main Chat Screen where I am calling these two components in the render method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';
import {  StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';
import { MessageReciever } from '../components/MessageReciever';
import { MessageSender } from '../components/MessageSender';
import { Separator , SeparatorDate  } from '../components/List';


class ChatMessageScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>

          <Header/>

        <Content>


           <MessageReciever />
           <MessageSender />


        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ChatMessageScreen;
```

The problem I am facing is when I am calling these two components in the render method only one component is rendered either MessageReciever or MessageSender which is called first.

I am not able to understand the problem so Please have a  look at and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed my mistake actually in the render function of components I am wrapping the content inside the container so it is taking whole screen space so when I am calling these components inside my screen it is rendering that component  but each rendered with the space of whole screen in between two components. So just removed container from the components and everything is working fine.